# Alternatives to slow Where clause in VIEW

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose i have the following table, which is the result from a rather complicated query (in particular the tbale is **not materialized**)

```
| id | x  | y  | z  | x_2  | y_2  |
|----|----|----|----|------|------|
|  1 | AA | BB | CC | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | DD | EE | FF | GG   | HH   |
|  3 | II | JJ | KK | LL   | MM   |
|  4 | NN | OO | PP | NULL | NULL |
```

I want to replicate rows where `x_2` is `NOT NULL` and override `x` (`y`) by `x_2`(`y_2`) in these replications.

Desired output should thus be the following:

```
| id | x  | y  | z  |
|----|----|----|----|
|  1 | AA | BB | CC |
|  2 | DD | EE | FF |
|  2 | GG | HH | FF |
|  3 | II | JJ | KK |
|  3 | LL | MM | KK |
|  4 | NN | OO | PP |
```

My (working) attempt is the following:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #pivot
CREATE TABLE #pivot(id INT, x CHAR(2), y CHAR(2), z CHAR(2), x_2 CHAR(2), y_2 CHAR(2))
INSERT INTO #pivot VALUES (1, 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', NULL, NULL), 
                          (2, 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'GG', 'HH'),
                          (3, 'II', 'JJ', 'KK', 'LL', 'MM'),
                          (4, 'NN', 'OO', 'PP', NULL, NULL)

SELECT id
       , x
       , y
       , z
  FROM #pivot

UNION ALL

SELECT id
       , x_2 AS x
       , y_2 AS y
       , z
  FROM #pivot
 WHERE x_2 IS NOT NULL
```

Eventually, I want to build a `VIEW` from this query, which I could use in several of my stored procedures. Since the base tables, which I use in my query are not under my control, I cannot add indices to them. Nor do I want to create a table instead of the `VIEW` because I want that the data in the `VIEW` is up-to-date whenever the procedures are requesting it.

While this works nicely for this toy example, my real case consists of 1.8 million rows with 14 columns (4 columns of which are the replacement columns like `x_2` and `y_2` in this toy example) and the `WHERE` clause seems to take forever.

From my novice understanding it kind of makes sense as there is no index on `x_2`(or any of the other replacement columns), as they are created on the fly.

My question thus is how I should proceed to achieve the following goals:

1. I want to have **one** single data source for my procedures (to make sure that all my procedures use the same data and to avoid hard coding the same query into several procedures).
2. This entry point should be up to date with the live data whenever the procedures are requesting it.
3. I do not want to use any scheduler/trigger to make sure that data is up-to-date

From my point of view I have a couple of options:

1. VIEW: this is the current approach, but results in a very slow `WHERE` clause as I cannot add an index to this field
2. A table valued function. I could create a temporary table within this function add an index to it and proceed.
3. Use another query which avoid the `IS NOT NULL` clause.

Any hitns of how I could get my desired outcome in a decent amount of time?

Comment: What sorts of WHERE criteria do you need to apply?

Comment: The `WHERE` is the same as in my toy example, so for building the final table I do a `WHERE x_2 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I played with the code a bit and instead of trying to do everything in one run, I stored the results from my query in a temp table, added an index on the `x_2` and used the `UNION ALL` clause with the temp table. This gives very reasonable timings. This indicates that I should rather use a table valued function instead of `VIEW` I assume.

Comment: Not if you plan to use a temporary table in a table value function; that's be awful for performance.

Comment: So what options do i have? All my debugging showed that the `WHERE` clause is the culprit and I can tremendously speed the whole query up when defining an index. To define an index, I need a table (variable), thus I have to go for a table valued function. Did I kiss something?

Comment: Find the person who can add the indexes.

Comment: an indexed view, at least for the IS NULL part (..if the prerequisites for index views are met) might be a viable option (datasource: table union indexed_view)

Comment: @RazvanSocol how would that help? I would need to index `x_2` and this column is the result of a query, i.e. it is generated on the fly. To index it it would need to be materialized - so unless I change my query to avoid the `IS NULL` altogether, I think I need some sort of storage where I can add an index.

Comment: You wrote "Suppose i have the following table..." If that was true, then add an index on x_2 column on that table. If not, try adding an index on the column in the base table that is used for computing this column.

Comment: Good point will clarify that in the original post.

Comment: I do not feel for your union in this case. It'll most likely lead to SQL Server scaning the large table twice.

Try this in stead: -----           
SELECT id
       , iif(b.n=0,x,x_2) x
       , iif(b.n=0,y,y_2) y
       , z
  FROM #pivot a
  inner join (values(0),(1)) b(n)
  on b.n=0 or a.x_2 is not null      ----,
although it might not work so well with your indexes ;)